# How to ignore database schema changes when switching branches in Rails?

Tags: git, ruby-on-rails-4, branching-and-merging

I am working on a large RoR application which requires splitting the work in multiple branches each having a different schema.

Is there a way to ignore schema changes when switching between branches?

Adding to .gitignore is not a good way since the merges would fail.

Also having different databases for each branch could be painful if you are working with a lot of branches.

Anyone has any ideas on how to solve for this problem?

Comment: "Is there a way to ignore schema changes when switching between branches?" What does this mean? Your database probably isn't (and certainly shouldn't be) tracked.

Comment: Whenever you switch branches the code gets switched but not the schema/database. One solution i found is to dump the db, reload the schema and then seed in the dumped file.

Comment: Your comment says exactly the opposite of what your question says. Are you looking for a workflow that *automatically updates* your database schema to match the active branch?

Comment: It isn't. There is no such thing as automatic switch unless you have separate db for each branch per the answer below, so i was just looking for workaround the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working on not just adding new fields and tables but making major schema changes, you can add and migrate all the constructive changes for the feature branch without breaking the tables and columns that exist for the schema defined in the initial branch. Then when the changes are tested and working as expected on the feature branch you can add migrations to remove the extra columns and tables that aren't needed.

Alternatively, if you're comfortable developing using tests instead of using preset seed data in the dev db and hacking in the console to see if your code works,  you could add all the migrations on your feature branch but only migrate the test db with `bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test`. This assumes, however, that you won't need to run your test suite on your original branch until you merge the changes you've been working on. Hope this gives you some options.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think the second option sounds like a better solution for my problem, otherwise you would end up with a lot of migration files.